# Add a new UIView programmatically with different data inside

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Background: I need to create a draggable ball with a different number and name inside every time I call the `addButtonClicked` action. Cannot really understand the approach here. Ball is showing and moving around correctly but how can I add different data for every new ball?

Is it possible to create something like a prototype cell for UIView?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //VAR
    var playerName = ""
    var number = ""
    var balls = [UIView]()

    @IBOutlet weak var ball: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        if let view = recognizer.view {
            view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                                  y:view.center.y + translation.y)
        }
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
    }

    // ACTIONS
    @IBAction func addButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        let newBall=UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50))

        // Change UIView background colour
        newBall.backgroundColor=UIColor.white

        // Add rounded corners to UIView
        newBall.layer.cornerRadius=25

        // Add border to UIView
        newBall.layer.borderWidth=0

        let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
        newBall.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

        // Add UIView as a Subview
        self.view.addSubview(newBall)

        balls.append(newBall)
        print ([balls])
    }
```

---

EDIT :

when i add  `let player1 = mycustomUIview())` it says cannot call value of non-function type 'mycustomUIView'
if i call `mycustomUiView.instantiatefromNib` in ViewController It shows the whole customView.
My idea is just to press a + button and create different draggable balls with data to change inside (screenshot ref: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkEfZ.jpg)
I tried to create different UIViews, even one different viewController for every player, but no luck, i can't find a single working solution online.

MyCustomUIViewController (outlets connected from MyCustomUIView.xib)

```
class playerBall: UIView {


@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var contentViewBall: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var contentViewNumberLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var contentViewNameLabel: UILabel!

// MARK: - Initializers

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}


// Performs the initial setup.
private func setupView() {
    let view = viewFromNibForClass()
    view.frame = bounds

    // Auto-layout
    view.autoresizingMask = [
        UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth,
        UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight
    ]

    // Show view.
    addSubview(view)
}

// Load XIB file into view and return this view.
 func viewFromNibForClass() -> UIView {

    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView

    return view
}
```

}

MainViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    playerBall.contentViewNameLabel.text = "Player"
    playerBall.contentViewNumberLabel.text = "10"

}



@IBOutlet weak var playerBall: playerBall!


@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {



    var customView = playerBall.viewFromNibForClass()
    self.view.addSubview(customView)



 }   


}
```

Comment: What data do you want different for each ball view?

Comment: Different Name, Different Number. Img reference: https://imgur.com/a/6OATe. Ideally, I'd like to control it like a prototype cell, so i can perform segue and insert different notes on the balls.

Comment: Create a custom view with whatever subviews and properties you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i created your desired effect with the following: -

i created a xib file which i called PlayerBall.xib, i have added to labels and changed the background color to clear color..

i then created a new coca touch class PlayerBall.swift which is a subclass of UIView.

change the class of the xib file to PlayerBall instead of the standard UIView

connect the outlets of the labels to the newly created class. it should look as follows:

```
class PlayerBall: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var playerNumber: UILabel!{
        didSet{
            playerNumber.layer.cornerRadius = playerNumber.frame.width / 2
            playerNumber.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var playerName: UILabel!


    class func instanceFromNib() -> PlayerBall {
        return UINib(nibName: "PlayerBall", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! PlayerBall
    }

}
```

now in the main viewController to test the code i added the following

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    for i in 1...5 {
        let ball = PlayerBall.instanceFromNib()
        ball.playerNumber.text  = "\(i)"
        ball.playerName.text = "Player " + ball.playerNumber.text!
        let randomX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(view.frame.width))
        let randomY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(view.frame.height))
        ball.center = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(randomX), y: CGFloat(randomY))
        view.addSubview(ball)
    }


}
```

The result is as follows:
[image: the result]

you can add more functionality to the custom class i just kept it basic as a proof of concept.

i hope this helps

Comment: Amazing! Thats what i needed! 
now I guess that if i add 'instanceforNib()' inside an 'action' it should create a new ball so i can have zero balls when app loads. 
if i want to tap the new created ball to segue to a second viewController, should i create that programmatically, right? Amazing.

Comment: Absolutely...you can add more customization to the custom view if you desire

Comment: And if your satisfied with the answer please accept it...and if you require more assistance please let me know

Comment: yes, just one little thing, how do i instantiate the genericViewController() to show additional data for any ball? 
I could not figure it out before.

Comment: Just Name, Number, and some additional notes.. as per screenshot (https://imgur.com/a/7GAsX). challenge is, do I connect it programmatically inside the action, or should I do it in another way?

Comment: It depends if you will be interacting with the views after you add them to the viewController or you just want to display the players on the field...if all you want to do is display them on the view then adding them from within the IBAction is fine